Can I banish myself to the feywild as a fairy who's native to the feywild from the material plane?
This somewhat ties in to a question
I asked before, but not entirely. In that question I was asking how to get back if I am banished, and I learned about fey crossings from the answer.
Now that I know I can get back, I was wondering, can I banish myself using banishment to escape if my entire party dies except for me, and then grow my power until I'm strong enough to win? In addition, if I can, would I still have to roll a charisma save to resist, or would I instead roll to see if I'm in danger wherever I end up in the feywild?

It is worth considering the story implications of this kind of thing well before the mechanical ones. If you are the only character alive and suddenly in another plane the DMs plans have gone significantly sideways.

I'm mostly trying to be prepared in case this type of situation actually happens, as we're coming up on a possible boss fight and I want to be prepared for a tpk in case it happens

Sorry if my question seems stupid

Tasi, not a stupid question, but it has been asked before.  I have closed it as a duplicate - the linked question even covers your question about the saving throw.  If you believe your question is different, please explain how / why and it can be reopened.

Why did that question not show up in related questions when I was asking?

I'm afraid that's above my paygrade.  It could be your search was directed at specific terms like feywild and did not emphasize enough general terms like banishment.

Alright, thanks for the help.

Sometime, search is weird. I recently found out that I had asked an exact duplicate of a question years later and received answers because I didn't find it and people forgot the other question was asked 6 years prior. Even the answering person was the same!
